# column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am creating a web app using springboot and thymeleaf but i keep getting the error "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'colName', table 'myTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails"

this is my html template:

```
    <form action="/insert" class="insertForm" th:object="${insertData}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group container-fluid">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="input" placeholder="Name" th:field="${insertData.firstName}" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group container-fluid d-flex">
        <input type="text" id="tel" class="input" placeholder="Phone Number" th:field="${insertData.phoneNumber}" required />
      </div>
      <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" th:field="${insertData.access}" required="required">
        <option th:value="1">Public</option>
        <option th:value="2">Private</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="input insertBtn" />
    </form>
```

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String showContacts(Model model) throws SQLException {
              --------some stuff-------------
        model.addAttribute("insertData", insertModel);

        return "main/Main";
    }
    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public String insertData(@ModelAttribute("insertData") InsertModel insertModel){
        InsertRepository insertRepository = new InsertRepository();
        insertRepository.insertOp();
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

my model

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InsertModel {
    private String firstName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int access;
}
```

my insertRepository

```
@Component
public class InsertRepository extends DataSource{
    public void insertOp(){
        InsertModel insertModel= new InsertModel();
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("Use PhoneBook "+"insert into dbo.contacts (FullName , PhoneNumber ,ownerId , auth) values ( ? , ? ,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, insertModel.getFirstName());
            pst.setString(2, insertModel.getPhoneNumber());
            pst.setInt(3, LoginModel.getUserId());
            pst.setInt(4, insertModel.getAccess());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

this form is intended for an insert operation in mssql server but its not working

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the `InsertRepository` ? What `insertRepository.insertOp()` is doing?

Comment: i have edited insert repository into my question

Comment: You try to init `InsertModel insertModel= new InsertModel();` and afterwards use fields in the insert. I guess `firstName` and `phoneNumber` in this case are null.

Comment: thanks @artiomi , that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/insert")
    public String insertData(@ModelAttribute("insertData") InsertModel insertModel){
        InsertRepository insertRepository = new InsertRepository();
        // 'insertRepository' is empty object
        insertRepository.insertOp();
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

May be you are trying to store empty value.

```
 @PostMapping("/insert")
            public String insertData(@ModelAttribute("insertData") InsertModel insertData){
                InsertRepository insertRepository = new InsertRepository();
                insertRepository.insertOp(insertData);
                return "redirect:/home";
            }

@Component
public class InsertRepository extends DataSource{
    public void insertOp(InsertModel insertModel){
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("Use PhoneBook "+"insert into dbo.contacts (FullName , PhoneNumber ,ownerId , auth) values ( ? , ? ,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, insertModel.getFirstName());
            pst.setString(2, insertModel.getPhoneNumber());
            pst.setInt(3, LoginModel.getUserId());
            pst.setInt(4, insertModel.getAccess());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe you have imported the LoginModel class in your insertRepository and your prepared statement is working fine. I guess this should work.

'LoginModel.getUserId()' if this is empty it will still show the same the error. See that it returns the Login user Id.